# dynamic datasource for jdbctemplate with no transaction manager

Tags: java, spring, transactions, c3p0, spring-transactions

I have a scenario, wherein I need to dynamically switch the data source during application run
 time.

For this I have JDBCManager class which maintains a map of pooled datasources (C3P0), on request of a particular spring jdbctemplate, I looked at key and return appropriate jdbctemplate with data source. as below

```
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(long targetId) throws DataAccessDeniedException {
    return new JdbcTemplate(this.map.get(targetId));
```

}

***I have not configured any transaction manager in my config, nor I have attached any transaction manager while I pragmatically creating a Datasourec as below***

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = null;
    dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    // DataSource dataSource = DataSources.unpooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(userId);
    dataSource.setPassword(userPassword);

    DataSource pooledDataSource;
    try {
        Map<String, Object> overrides = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        overrides.put("minPoolSize", minPoolSize);
        overrides.put("maxPoolSize", maxPoolSize);
        overrides.put("acquireIncrement", acquireIncrement);
        overrides.put("maxIdleTime", maxIdleTime);
        overrides.put("idleConnectionTestPeriod", idleConnectionTestPeriod);
        overrides.put("maxIdleTimeExcessConnections", maxIdleTimeExcessConnections);
        overrides.put("numHelperThreads", numHelperThreads);
        overrides.put("unreturnedConnectionTimeout", unreturnedConnectionTimeout);
        overrides.put("checkoutTimeout", checkoutTimeout);

        // create the PooledDataSource with overrides
        pooledDataSource = DataSources.pooledDataSource(dataSource, overrides);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Could not create pooled datasource for target: " + targetId);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }        
    // cache the pooledDataSource
    this.map.put(targetId, pooledDataSource);

    return pooledDataSource;
}
```

Currently I am facing issue wherein After few minutes of processing my c3p0 connection pool runs out of connections and everything starts failing with following error

```
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@65d43d1e -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1416)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:756)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:683)
... 61 more
```

I suspect something is wrong with transactions or there is connection leak.

My doubt is will jdbctemplate release / manage connections appropriately when there is no transaction manager configured?

Comment: I don't understand the scenario do you need to switch the DS(e.g. kill the old DS and replace it with a new one) or you need a pool as you implemented it. Why you use DriverManagerDataSource? It's a simple impl and returns new connection every time. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html

Comment: I maintain a pool of datasources in a map

Comment: try to use apache datasource.
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

Comment: I don't have control over this source,hence need to,live with it. But do you see its because of DriverManagerDataSource?  my question is , does jdbctemplate takes care of connection management?